# i am geting an error that "SQL command not properly ended" for this query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT 
HEADER_ID
FROM 
XXCORP.XXCORP_OM_DEALER_FEE_DIS_HDR as h, 
XXCORP.XXCORP_OM_DEALER_FEE_DIS_LIN,
OE_ORDER_HEADERS_ALL
WHERE h.FEE_ID = XXCORP_OM_DEALER_FEE_DIS_LIN.FEE_ID (+) 
AND h.HEADER_ID(+) = OE_ORDER_HEADERS_ALL.HEADER_ID 
AND (XXCORP.XXCORP_OM_DEALER_FEE_DIS_LIN.LAST_UPDATE_DATE > TO_DATE('03/10/2019 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: In addition what jarlh wrote: even Oracle recommends to stop using the proprietary `(+)` operator

Comment: I'm sure there are better ways to write this query.  Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the logic is supposed to be doing.

Comment: @jarlh, *= much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table name shouldn't have `AS` for the alias, here:

```
XXCORP.XXCORP_OM_DEALER_FEE_DIS_HDR as h, 
                                    --
                                    this! --> remove "as"
```

Example which illustrates it:

```
SQL> select * From dept as d;
select * From dept as d
                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended


SQL> select * from dept d;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

Comment: it worked also i needed to give alias.HEADER_ID in the select statement

Comment: Yes, if it is contained in more than one table (as Oracle doesn't know which one to take).